# vertical-align does't work within list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to align text inside my list by the bottom line. I use vertical-align css option, but it doesn't work.
You can find code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/kL4AX/2/
Thanks in advance

Comment: Here's an article on vertical align.  It's not straightforward at all.  Not at first, anyhow.  http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: vertical-align exists primarily for tables and usually should be used with display:table-cell; butt.. if you use that then you can't use display:inline-block; so instead you'll have to use one of the many workarounds for this and just accept its limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use positioning to move the `<h1>` elements to the bottom of the list items like in this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kL4AX/3/)**

```
.navigator ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 400px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    position:relative;
}

.navigator ul li h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try positioning the H1 as absolute with bottom, or if you have a fixed height for your `<li>` you can use a padding-top value to make sure the H1 is placed at the bottom.

Vertical-align wont center or position an element in respect to its parent.